# Google Sheets Script Editor Triggers not Working

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a simple script that works 100% of the time that I manually run it, but if I set a trigger it does not.

**My trigger:**
[image]

**My script:**

```js
function sendEmail() {    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var excelCheck = "B" + (hours + 3);
    var excelCheck2 = "C" + (hours + 3);
    var istrue = sheet.getRange(excelCheck).getValue();
    var istrue2 = sheet.getRange(excelCheck2).getValue();
    
    if ( istrue == "TRUE" ){
      MailApp.sendEmail('pedro@pedroferrari.com', 'GA-alert Spam', 'Too many visits in the last hour. Check it up!');
    }
    if ( istrue2 == "TRUE" ){
      MailApp.sendEmail('pedro@pedroferrari.com', 'GA-alert Slow', 'Website is underperforming. Check it up!');
    }
  }
}
```

What happens is that if I manually run the script, I will get the email if my Sheet has a TRUE value in that cell.
Even if I do a FOR loop with `Utilities.sleep(300 * 1000);`, it works, but there is a maximum wait time of 5 minutes, plus it is clearly not the way to do it.

**Although, if I do something like this:**

```js
function sendEmail() {    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var excelCheck = "B" + (hours + 3);
    var excelCheck2 = "C" + (hours + 3);
    var istrue = sheet.getRange(excelCheck).getValue();
    var istrue2 = sheet.getRange(excelCheck2).getValue();
    
    // This will send
    MailApp.sendEmail('pedro@pedroferrari.com', istrue2, istrue);
    
    // These will not
    if ( istrue == "TRUE" ){
      MailApp.sendEmail('pedro@pedroferrari.com', 'GA-alert Spam', 'Too many visits in the last hour. Check it up!');
    }
    if ( istrue2 == "TRUE" ){
      MailApp.sendEmail('pedro@pedroferrari.com', 'GA-alert Slow', 'Website is underperforming. Check it up!');
    }
  }
}
```

Then the trigger works for the first email, with the variables being the correct subject/content. It does not work for the other two emails.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a trigger, you don't have an "active" context anymore.
So, it doesn't seem relevant to use `getActiveSheet`.

You'd better specify the sheet you are targetting:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
```